# ReactJS hide header on invalid page(404)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I've recently started learning React and I've been trying to figure out how I would go about hiding my header when the user is trying to route to an invalid page/path. The only way I can think of is to manually add  to each of my components and remove the  from my App.js. For now I'm simply redirecting them to the home page. Below are my App and Root JS files. Before I had `<Redirect to="/" />`, I used `<Route component={invalidPage}/>` to link to an InvalidPage component, but couldn't figure out a way to hide the header.

```
//App.js
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Root>  
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home}/>
                        <Route exact path={"/user"} component={User}/>
                        <Route exact path={"/home"} component={Home}/>      
                        <Redirect to="/"/>
                    </Switch>
                </Root>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

//Root.js
export class Root extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <Header/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Higher Order Components. This approach should basically work. Tell me if you face difficulties.

```
//App.js
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={"/"} component={withRoot(Home)}/>
            <Route exact path={"/user"} component={withRoot(User)}/>
            <Route exact path={"/home"} component={withRoot(Home)}/>
            <Route component={invalidPage}/>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const withRoot= (Component)=> <Root><Component/></Root>
```

Comment: That seems like an elegant solution. I'm still new to React, so I was wondering how this performance compares to pasting <Root>'s content inside each of the other components. My guess would be that this is more efficient because only 1 route will match and only that 1 route will have the header added on.

Comment: Never mind. Your users are not going to navigate to a new page too often. And React is meant to compose, and is very good at it.

Comment: I tried the above and got this error: `"Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."` Not sure what this means

Comment: Try adding tags or curly braces around the component name. Sorry not able to check in details as I am on my phone right now.

Comment: Wasn't able to get it to work. I tried searching around and I couldn't find anything to explain how `const withRoot= (Component)=> <Root><Component/></Root>` works or the error I got.

Comment: Try searching for higher order components

Comment: I did and it seems that const withRoot would have to return a component, but in the code above it's only returning JSX. WIth that said, I changed `withRoot` to this and it worked: `function includeHeader(Component){
 return class includeHeaderComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
   return (
    <Root>
     <Component/>
    </Root>
   );
  }
 };
}`

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out! I had tried out my answer in a slightly different context before posting. React syntax can be oh-so-subtle! :)