# How can I hide header for 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<HeaderContainer>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/counters' component={ParentCounterContainer}/>
    <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutContainer} />
    <Route exact path='/' component={HomeContainer}/>
    <Route component={ErrorContainer} />
  </Switch>
</HeaderContainer>
```

How can I wrap all routes except `ErrorContainer` in `HeaderContainer`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS hide header on invalid page(404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944836/reactjs-hide-header-on-invalid-page404)

Comment: its not an idle way to define your rotes in header you should define your navlinks there and put your routes where you want to show it

Comment: if you are using redux you can use redux state

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the 404 page component Route outside the HeaderContainer.

```
<Switch>
  <HeaderContainer>
      <Route exact path='/counters' component={ParentCounterContainer}/>
      <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutContainer} />
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomeContainer}/>
  </HeaderContainer>
  <Route component={ErrorContainer} />
<Switch>
```

Comment: Then it will always be shown since it's not in the `Switch`.

Comment: It still not working. Header is still here, but ErrorContainer not displaying at all

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Header />
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => {return <Component {...props} />}}/>
)

export default CustomRoute;
```

Try Custom Routing like this. It may work.

App router

```
  <Switch>
    <CustomRoute exact path='/counters' component={ParentCounterContainer}/>
    <CustomRoute exact path='/about' component={AboutContainer} />
    <CustomRoute exact path='/' component={HomeContainer}/>
    <Route component={ErrorContainer} />
  </Switch>
```